# Excel : count occurences found in another range matching criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

I'm pretty sure a combinaison of COUNTIFS, SUMPRODUCT, VLOOKUP, INDEX or MATCH would do the trick, but really I can't get in Excel logic and not able to do it. The closest matches I found are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261929/excel-counting-no-of-items-in-a-different-sheet-between-a-certain-range-matchi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51643581/how-to-count-from-an-looked-up-range-in-excel), but I was not able to transpose it. Help much appreciated.

Here is a sample of problem with expected output in yellow.
So for instance, E2 is the number of value greater than 1 we found in range B2:B7 for which product is equal to A.

[image]

Sorry F3 is wrong, it should be 2 (we have 2 value of B product greater than 2)

Comment: COUNTIFS should be all you need.

Comment: Well I able to do use =COUNTIF(B2:B7;">=1") but how to add the lookup between product ?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A2:A7;D2;B2:B7;">=1")`

Comment: pfff it make me sad to not having found it by myself and being so bad but yes this is working perfectly. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to BigBen:

Formula to use and transpose:
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7;$D2;$B$2:$B$7;">1")

[image]